# Read command line in assembly

Tags: parsing, assembly, command-line-arguments, nasm

First time I play with ds, si and strings related instructions in assembly. I am trying to read the command line arguments char by char and this is how my code looks like now:

```
GetCommandLine:
    push                    ebp
    mov                     ebp,    esp
    push edi
    push esi
    call                    GetCommandLineW
    mov edi, eax
    mov esi, ebp
    Parse:
        lodsw
        cmp                 ax,     0dh ; until return is found
        jne                 Parse
    pop esi
    pop edi
    pop ebp
    ret
```

So, the `GetCommandLineW` function returns a correct pointer to the string. The problem is that the `Parse` section loops forever and I can't see the AX register being loaded with the correct next byte from the string. I think the *EDI:ESI* is not correctly loaded or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`esi` and `edi` are different pointers. `ebp` is used for saving the old stack pointer, and for saving/loading local variables. `GetCommandLineW` will return the pointer in `eax`, which you should then put into `esi`. Since you're only using `lodsw` (and not `stos*`), you don't need to touch `edi`.

Comment: Done. Now I can see how esi increments correctly (word by word). Does lodsw load the byte of the address of the byte in the AX register? I use OllyDbg to debug this and I don't see the EAX register filled with  the char of each loop

Comment: `lodsw` loads the word (not byte) that `esi` currently points to and stores it into `ax`, then increments `esi` by two. If you're looking at it in a debugger, you'll need to ignore the upper-half of `eax` since you're only modifying the lower-half (aka `ax`).

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think that 0x0d is used in the commandline? A normal C string is returned, so you should look for a 0 byte.

Comment: Thanks. So it's the '\0' terminator that marks the end, right?

Comment: Yes. I just tested it with a simple program and there is no 0x0d. Plain old C string. :)